# Redis: Redisinsight : Error while connecting : "Something went wrong adding the database. Please try again"

Tags: redis, redisinsights

I have a Redis server that I am trying to connect to for Mule 4 applications.

My objective is :

1. Connect with Redis using Mule 4 app : Success
2. Connect with Redis using Redisinsight to visualise the data -> Problem

While connecting using Redisinsight I do the following :

- Launch the Redisinsight tool. It starts the tool at : http://localhost:8001/
- Click on  "I already have a database"
- Click on "Connect to a Redis Database"
- Here I provide the host, port, name (which as per documentation I provide anything say redis_test) and password.

I get the error message : "Something went wrong adding the database. Please try again"

Interestingly while connecting by mule, I just need to provide host, port and password and it works.

Please help. Thanks in advance

From the redisinsight logs :

```
ERROR 2021-02-09 14:14:20,123 django.request Internal Server Error: /api/instance/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
  File "django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
  File "django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
  File "django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
  File "django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
  File "rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
  File "rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
  File "rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
  File "redisinsight\core\views\instance.py", line 208, in post
  File "redisinsight\core\views\instance.py", line 147, in _save_redis_instance
  File "redisinsight\core\services\database\_routines.py", line 80, in _wrapped_add_db_func
  File "redisinsight\core\services\database\_routines.py", line 765, in add_redis_database
  File "redisinsight\core\services\database\_routines.py", line 809, in add_standalone_db
  File "redisinsight\core\services\database\_routines.py", line 576, in _add_standalone_db
  File "redisinsight\core\services\database\_routines.py", line 190, in _assert_db_type
  File "redisinsight\core\services\database\_routines.py", line 175, in _probe_db_type
  File "redis\client.py", line 1281, in info
  File "redis\client.py", line 878, in execute_command
  File "redis\client.py", line 892, in parse_response
  File "redis\connection.py", line 752, in read_response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: unknown command `INFO`, with args beginning with:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable INFO command
Edit the Redis config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

search for the INFO command

something like:

```
rename-command INFO ""
```

Comment the line and restart redis:

```
systemctl restart redis
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `INFO` command is disabled on your Redis server. RedisInsight needs basic commands like `INFO` and `PING` to be enabled.

Comment: How do I enable it?